# Node Gallery not using administration theme for its custom tabs

Tags: theming

I'm using a very minimal custom theme for the website, but Bartik for administration.

Node Gallery plugin adds tabs to the Edit Node page (e.g. `node/46/edit`): "Manage Items", "Sort items" and "Upload new items". When I click on them, **the custom theme is used instead of Bartik**. I suspect this is because these pages weren't properly flagged as admin pages, or something like that.

**How can I make Node Gallery use administration theme for its custom tabs?**

Answer (score 3):

Generally, to declare a path as an admin path (and thus one that would open in the overlay/use the admin theme, etc.) you need to declare them using [hook_admin_paths](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7).

If this is the issue (I don't know Node Gallery, so I can't be more precise) the best would be to implement hook_admin_paths in the Node Gallery module and submit the patch on the Node Gallery issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Bartik (your admin theme) not being used just for the extra tabs provided by Node Gallery? Or it not being used for the regular node/edit pages either?

If it is the later case and you are on Drupal 7, you can goto `admin/appearance` and at the bottom of the page set your 'administration theme' and check the option to use it during content editing.

[image: Setting the content editing theme for Drupal]